# Vue3 - How to use instance initiated in parent component's onMounted hook, in the child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am having an issue where I initiate a variable (tabulator) in the onMounted() life cycle hook, so when I pass the tabulator instance as prop to the child component, it will always be null because I suppose the initiated happens after the child component is created.

Simply put: I want to use an instance that is declared and initiated in the parent component, in the child component.

Tabulator requires me to initiate it in the onMounted() hook, so I can't get away from that.

**Parent component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <AddRowButton :tabulator="tabulator" />
        <div ref="table"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables'
import AddRowButton from '@/components/buttons/AddRowButton.vue'

interface Props {
    data: Array
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    data: Array
})

let tabulator = null
const table = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    tabulator = new Tabulator(table.value, {
        data: props.data,
        columns: [
            { title: 'Id', field: 'id', sorter: 'number' },
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name', sorter: 'string' },
            { title: 'Email', field: 'email', sorter: 'string' },
            { title: 'Date', field: 'date', sorter: 'date' }
        ]
    })
})
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
    <button @click="addNewRow">Add row</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables'

defineProps({
    tabulator: Tabulator
})

function addNewRow(): void {
    try {
        tabulator.addData({}, true) // Tabulator always null
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the tabulator prop as type null

```
defineProps({
  tabulator: null
})
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. What should I define it as? Updated code snippet to use Tabulator as type, but still same issue :)

Comment: Okay, now try making it reactive with ref()

Comment: If I do this, then it works:

let tabulator = ref(null)
// In onMounted() life cycle hook.
tabulator.value = Tabulator(...)
tabulator.value.on(...)

Thanks. Not sure this is the proper way to do it though? :)

Comment: Yes! It's the right way! The issue was the variable wasn't reactive so it wasn't reflecting the change in the child component.